# Auto-increment field of six digits

Tags: java, db2

I have a table with an "identifier" attribute. 
I need this attribute to be unique and auto-incremented by one (length of the attribute must be six digits).

For example the first time I persist an entity, the identifier should be 000001 and the second one 000002 and so on.

Could you please tell me how to implement this requirement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why? Usually the need to do something like this indicates a catastrophic design flaw. Waht happens when teh id gets to 999999?

Comment: @Tony you know the answer

Comment: @morpheus05. Well I could maka couple of assumptions and call them an answer. :( :( :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to convert your number as a String. 
To do so, you can use String.format.

```
 String.format("%06d", num)
```

'0' The gaps are filled with 0.
'6' The result has a size of 6.
'd' The result is formatted as a decimal integer.

For example:

```
 int num = 8;
 String var = String.format("%06d", num);
```

will return:

```
 var = "000008"
```

**EDIT: The syntax of String.format can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax**

If you want to retrieve an ID from your base, just parse the String as a Number:

```
String identifier = "000008"; // Returned ID from database
Number num = Integer.parseInt(identifier); // num = 8
```

Comment: Thank you Guillaume for your reply :) the second part of my question is what is the most efficient way to know the max number inserted in the database ?

Comment: @user2490510: you shouldn't even have to know that. Use a database sequence or an auto-increment field. The database must generate the ID for you. By the time you get the max from the database, it might not be the max anymore, since several transactions are executed in parallel.

Comment: @user2490510 As said above, you better use a sequence to auto-increment the ID. The max ID can be retrieved with Select Max(id) from YourTable

Comment: Thank u JB & Guillaume , How can i use sequence or auto-increment field with the format "000000" ? could u please explain more ?

Comment: Just use an every day auto inc. Then when you need it in this daft format, use teh Code @Guillaume.M supplied